# Simple sample space probability question

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

> In sets $A$ and $B$, $n(A) = 9$, $n(A'∩ B) = 2$ and $n(A'∩ B') =3 $. The set belongs to a sample space with 14 elements. If an element is selected at random, the probability that it is in $A∩B$ is?

I have been trying to figure out this question for some while now, and while I do understand that the solution may be 2/7, by method of Karnaugh map (probability table - I would prefer if a solution was provided with this method), but could someone please explain why it can't also be 1/14 (as that's the answer I got initially, even with a Venn diagram).

Comment: $n(A\cap B)$ is not determined here. It can take values in $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$. So the probability you mention is also undetermined.

Comment: What is n(set)? Is it the cardinality of the set?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, yes, n(set) stands for number of elements within the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $n(set)$ is the cardinality of the set (it is consistent with the numbers given after all) the question cannot be answered, at least not with a single number.

To find the probability of a randomly selected element to belong in $A\cap B$ we need to know $n(A \cap B)$. We cannot find this with the information given. We need to **also** know either $n(B)$, **or** $n(B')$, **or** $n(A \cap B)$, **or** $n(A\cap B')$. Can you see why?

Without knowing anything more, set $B$ can have all elements common with set $A$ or none, or anything in between. This means that the probability of their intersection can range from $0/14$ to $9/14$. So both $1/14$ and $2/7$ could be valid answers.

Comment: Thank you for that, I just wasn't sure as the solutions stated otherwise.

Comment: @mathslover is there more context to the problem? I find it hard to believe that the problem is **exactly** as stated, and then the answer key gives an answer of 2/7. Maybe it's part of a larger set of problems and there is an overarching assumption there that it is not stated here.